# How to avoid calling memcpy() when appending to vector<array<char,N>>?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

The code below reads a binary file in 1024-byte chunks (blocks), saves them into `vector<array<char,1024>>` and, finally, prints first byte of each block:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
#include "string.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<array<char,1024>> blocks;
   vector<char> buffer(1024,0);

   ifstream input("./video.mp4", std::ifstream::binary);

   while( !input.eof() ) {
      input.read( buffer.data(), buffer.size() );
      auto size = input.gcount();

      array<char,1024> aa;
      memcpy( aa.data(), buffer.data(), size );

      blocks.push_back( aa );
   }

   for( auto b: blocks ) {
      cout<<hex<<setw(2)<<setfill('0')<<(int)(uint8_t)b[0]<<'\n';
   }
}
```

I would like to avoid calling `memcpy`, since this is arguably not *comme il faut*. How can I accomplish the above functionality using only C++ std library? I believe my compiler supports up to C11 only.

Comment: You can use std::copy. But it's also probably better to create an chunk inside the vector directly and then fill it.

Comment: You also probably want to read in chunks, but store the data contiguously, no?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you accomplish by using a temporary `vector` that you can't accomplish simply by reading each block into the `array` in the first place? Poof! No more need to memcpy anything anywhere!

Comment: yeah, I guess it would be more streamlined to read directly, I'll have to try that. I am just trying to refresh my C++ and couldn't figure out if I have `char *` how to add it to the vector using `std` calls only

Answer (score 1):

```
  block.emplace_back();
  try {
    input.read( block.back().data(), block.back().size() );
    auto size = input.gcount();
    std::fill_n(block.back().data()+size, block.back().size()-size, '\0' );
  } catch(...) {
    block.resize(block.size()-1);
    throw;
  }
```

This fills the last block with read data and then zeros the rest.  If an exception is thrown, it gives the strong exception guarantee.

Memory for the blocks grows expnentially, giving you a constant factor overallocation and an amortized linear number of bytes recopied.  If you know how many blocks (or even have a good guess) you can reserve beforehand.